# Simple menu works in chrome, fails in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Simple menu of in plain CSS / html as shown:

```
<div class="nav-container">
            <div id="corp-crumb">
                <ul class="vertlist" id="ulTop">
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="homeLink" href="#home" title="Home" class="crumblink">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="activitiesLink" href="#activities" title="Activities" class="crumblink">Activities</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Issues">Issues</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Meetings">Meetings</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="a1" href="#marketing" title="Marketing" class="crumblink">Marketing</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Corporate Groups">Corporate Groups</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Companies">Companies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="a2" href="#operations" title="Operations" class="crumblink">Operations</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Programs">Programs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Projects">Sub Projects</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="reportsLink" href="#reports" title="Reports" class="crumblink">Reports</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

When I hover over the `li` item I get a sub menu of the `ul` items.  In chrome the list functions correctly, if I hover over the li it stays open to select the sub menu.  In IE however, when I hover over it and then try to go to the `ul` sub item menu it quickly disappears.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncrwg/

Tested with both IE9 and IE10.

Comment: Currently I was looking at IE10 but even if I put it in compatibility mode it still fails.

Comment: For what it's worth, your menus in your fiddle don't work in Firefox either. So this isn't an IE-specific problem.

Comment: Also, what's with all the `* + html` and `* html` selectors?? That's an IE6/7 hack, if I recall correctly, which is fair enough if you really need it, but it's inside a media query, which IE6/7 don't support anyway, so they'll never get used.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was on to finding a solution that doesn't involve adding a border-top to the submenu's <ul>, but wading thru 2000+ lines of CSS is too hard. If you could update your fiddle to only include the relevant CSS I may give it another go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to close the gap between the navigation and the drop down `<ul>`.

Adding `top: -3px` to the `div#corp-crumb ul li ul` should fix this.

EDIT:

If you want to maintain the space use something like `border-top: 3px solid #FFF; top: -2px;`

Comment: The gap may part of the intended look tho.

Comment: @jingtao: the gap is what is causing the problem though. You can't have a gap there because it'll break the hover.

Comment: This probably should be a good fix, strange how chrome simply works.

Comment: Updated answer, adding a border to the drop down `<ul>` will maintain the space and also keep the hover active.